# Resizing images in C#

Tags: c#, resize, gdi

I have the below method which I found online,which resizes an image to an approximate size, while keeping the aspect ratio.

```
     public Image ResizeImage(Size size)
    {
        int sourceWidth = _Image.Width;
        int sourceHeight = _Image.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH > nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(_Image, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;
    }
```

I usually pass in a size with a width of 100px and a height of 100px - as part of my requirements I can't have any single dimension (height or width) being under 100px, so if the aspect ratio isn't square the other dimension would be higher.

What I'm finding with this method is occasionally one of the dimensions will be under 100px - such as 96px or 99px. How can I change this method to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: I think the simplest way would be to check destWidth or height for <100 if any are then multiply both w and h by a scalar derived from vals minimum/erroneous val (hopefully this would give a number similar to 1.05 (not wrote as answer as its easier to write comments on my phone!)

Comment: its bcz its maintaining aspect ratio of ur originasl picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is just inappropriate.  It doesn't score points for using floating point math, that has a knack for rounding the wrong way so you can easily end up with 99 pixels instead of 100.  Always favor integer math so you can control the rounding.  And it just doesn't do anything to ensure that one of the dimensions is large enough, the way to end up with 96 pixels.  Just write better code.  Like:

```
    public static Image ResizeImage(Image img, int minsize) {
        var size = img.Size;
        if (size.Width >= size.Height) {
            // Could be: if (size.Height < minsize) size.Height = minsize;
            size.Height = minsize;
            size.Width = (size.Height * img.Width + img.Height - 1) / img.Height;
        }
        else {
            size.Width = minsize;
            size.Height = (size.Width * img.Height + img.Width - 1) / img.Width;
        }
        return new Bitmap(img, size);
    }
```

I left a comment to show what you do if you are only want to make sure the image is large enough and accept larger images.  It wasn't clear from the question.  If that's the case then replicate that if statement in the else clause as well.

Comment: What is the " + img.Height - 1" for?

Comment: That ensures the size is always rounded up.

Comment: Yes, but why? Is there a corner case where that is necessary? It does introduce small errors (< 1 pixel) but I fail to see the necessity...

Comment: The OP didn't state a preference, other than that he really didn't like his original code rounding down.  A 0.5 avg pixel error is inevitable, the choice is to go up or down.  The code still produces a perfect fit if the scaling allows it.