# C#: Print image from file

Tags: c#, .net, windows, image, printing

I want to print an image from a file to fit to a page perfectly.

All I managed to code until now is this:

```
    private void button_print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.PrinterSettings = printDialog1.PrinterSettings;
            printDocument1.PrintPage += PrintPage;
            printDocument1.Print();          
        }
    }

    private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image img = imgOriginal;
        Point loc = new Point(0, 24);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);

    }
```

The problem here is, that the image is to big to fit perfectly to the page. What can I do? All the threads an questions I found with google are not that promising.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Marco Frost

Comment: So you want to resize an image to the size of the currently selected paper in the default printer? Do you want to break aspect-ratio?

Comment: Yes. I want to resize it. But I want to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: Could you try something like this : img.Width = pageSetupDialog.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width;

Comment: @EtienneArthur Unfortunately not. img.Width/.Height is read only. Furthermore it wouldn't keep the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  string filepath = "D:\\patient images\\" + txtPatCode.Text + "\\" + lstImages.SelectedItems[0].Text;
  System.Drawing.Image img = Image.FromFile(filepath);
  ResizeImage(img, 200);
  Point loc = new Point(200, 200);
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);           
}

public static Image ResizeImage(Image img, int minsize)
{
  var size = img.Size;
  if (size.Width >= size.Height)
  {
    // Could be: if (size.Height < minsize) size.Height = minsize;
    size.Height = minsize;
    size.Width = (size.Height * img.Width + img.Height - 1) / img.Height;
  }
  else
  {
    size.Width = minsize;
    size.Height = (size.Width * img.Height + img.Width - 1) / img.Width;
  }
  return new Bitmap(img, size);
}
```

Comment: You should attribute this answer [Resizing images in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15998683/719186) since your ResizeImage function seems to be copied from it.